# Generating multiple random (x, y) coordinates, excluding duplicates?

Tags: python, math, random, coordinates

I want to generate a bunch (x, y) coordinates from 0 to 2500 that excludes points that are within 200 of each other without recursion.

Right now I have it check through a list of all previous values to see if any are far enough from all the others. This is really inefficient and if I need to generate a large number of points it takes forever.

So how would I go about doing this?

Comment: One way would be to populate a list with all available points. Then pick a random element of your list and remove all points that are too close to it. This would be pretty expensive memory-wise though. One way to implement this would be a 2500 x 2500 array of 0-1 which represent valid or invalid. Generate x and y, if points[x][y] == 0 then set it to one and set everything in range x-100 to x+100 and y-100 to y+100. Removing points in a square would be easier than points in a 200 radius circle, if you can get away with that.

Comment: Are these points random? How random?

Comment: Draw a grid, placing the origin at random. Then take for points the centre of each square. Done.

Comment: @ColonelPanic That wouldn't be a very random distribution of points. Every points would have 4 points equidistant to it.

Answer (score 14):

This is a variant on Hank Ditton's suggestion that should be more efficient time- and memory-wise, especially if you're selecting relatively few points out of all possible points.  The idea is that, whenever a new point is generated, everything within 200 units of it is added to a set of points to exclude, against which all freshly-generated points are checked.

```
import random

radius = 200
rangeX = (0, 2500)
rangeY = (0, 2500)
qty = 100  # or however many points you want

# Generate a set of all points within 200 of the origin, to be used as offsets later
# There's probably a more efficient way to do this.
deltas = set()
for x in range(-radius, radius+1):
    for y in range(-radius, radius+1):
        if x*x + y*y <= radius*radius:
            deltas.add((x,y))

randPoints = []
excluded = set()
i = 0
while i<qty:
    x = random.randrange(*rangeX)
    y = random.randrange(*rangeY)
    if (x,y) in excluded: continue
    randPoints.append((x,y))
    i += 1
    excluded.update((x+dx, y+dy) for (dx,dy) in deltas)
print randPoints
```

Comment: Nice! It is certainly more efficient space-wise, but is it time-wise? In both algorithms we are generating a point, setting the same amount of points as excluded, and possibly throwing away the point if it is not valid.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Many of the points generated are on top of eachother.

Comment: @user2901745: Really?  The output looks as expected to me.  Do you mean the code is generating duplicate points in a single run?  Could you give an example?

Comment: Yeah, you can see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UKarh.png) that the points are overlapping. I'm using the generated list to paste random characters around this image (although, I'm having trouble getting this font to work, but that's a different problem). They're not duplicate, but they are within 200px of eachother. Here's two points that I found that were both generated in the same call: (1975, 2169), (1917, 2191)

Comment: @user2901745: Ah, I see what I did wrong.  I forgot to square `radius` in line 13, making the effective radius actually about 14.1.

Comment: Hm, well it does work now. But it's still pretty slow. I guess it's good enough though. I don't really need it to be incredibly fast.

Answer (score 8):

I would overgenerate the points, `target_N < input_N`, and filter them using a [KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix). For example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
N   = 20
pts = 2500*np.random.random((N,2))

tree = KDTree(pts)
print tree.sparse_distance_matrix(tree, 200)
```

Would give me points that are "close" to each other. From here it should be simple to apply any filter:

```
  (11, 0)   60.843426339
  (0, 11)   60.843426339
  (1, 3)    177.853472309
  (3, 1)    177.853472309
```

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

- Use your algorithm but implement it with a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) that would speed up nearest neighbours look-up
- Build a regular grid over the [0, 2500]^2 square and 'shake' all points randomly with a bi-dimensional normal distribution centered on each intersection in the grid
- Draw a larger number of random points then apply a [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means) algorithm and only keep the centroids. They will be far away from one another and the algorithm, though iterative, could converge more quickly than your algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered, but it's very tangentially related to my work so I took a stab at it. I implemented the algorithm described in [this note](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph07-poissondisk.pdf) which I found linked from [this blog post](http://www.coderhaus.com/?p=11). Unfortunately it's not faster than the other proposed methods, but I'm sure there are optimizations to be made.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lonely(p,X,r):
    m = X.shape[1]
    x0,y0 = p
    x = y = np.arange(-r,r)
    x = x + x0
    y = y + y0

    u,v = np.meshgrid(x,y)

    u[u < 0] = 0
    u[u >= m] = m-1
    v[v < 0] = 0
    v[v >= m] = m-1

    return not np.any(X[u[:],v[:]] > 0)

def generate_samples(m=2500,r=200,k=30):
    # m = extent of sample domain
    # r = minimum distance between points
    # k = samples before rejection
    active_list = []

    # step 0 - initialize n-d background grid
    X = np.ones((m,m))*-1

    # step 1 - select initial sample
    x0,y0 = np.random.randint(0,m), np.random.randint(0,m)
    active_list.append((x0,y0))
    X[active_list[0]] = 1

    # step 2 - iterate over active list
    while active_list:
        i = np.random.randint(0,len(active_list))
        rad = np.random.rand(k)*r+r
        theta = np.random.rand(k)*2*np.pi

        # get a list of random candidates within [r,2r] from the active point
        candidates = np.round((rad*np.cos(theta)+active_list[i][0], rad*np.sin(theta)+active_list[i][1])).astype(np.int32).T

        # trim the list based on boundaries of the array
        candidates = [(x,y) for x,y in candidates if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < m and y < m]

        for p in candidates:
            if X[p] < 0 and lonely(p,X,r):
                X[p] = 1
                active_list.append(p)
                break
        else:
            del active_list[i]

    return X

X = generate_samples(2500, 200, 10)
s = np.where(X>0)
plt.plot(s[0],s[1],'.')
```

And the results:

[image: Resulting sample pattern]

Comment: This would be an interesting set of points to do a data analysis on to look for trends or patterns. It doesn't seem completely random to me, but then again the fact that they have to be 200 pts from each other may be causing what looks like a pattern though it might not be.

Comment: I know it's old, but I couldn't get your code to run in Python 3.5.1. I added a few imports from `math` but at least it was a try. I'm still a bit of a beginner.

Comment: @RickHenderson I just updated the code and tested it in Python 3.5 - it's working for me!

Answer (score 0):

Per the link, the method from aganders3 is known as Poisson Disc Sampling.  You might be able to find more efficient implementations that use a local grid search to find 'overlaps.'  For example [Poisson Disc Sampling](https://scipython.com/blog/poisson-disc-sampling-in-python/).  Because you are constraining the system, it cannot be completely random.  The maximum packing for circles with uniform radii in a plane is ~90% and is achieved when the circles are arranged in a perfect hexagonal array.  As the number of points you request approaches the theoretical limit, the generated arrangement will become more hexagonal.  In my experience, it is difficult to get above ~60% packing with uniform circles using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic solution would be to

- add the generated coordinate pairs to an initially empty set-datastructure until it contains 2501 coordinate pairs.
- find the closest pair of points by e.g. checking the edges of their Voronoi diagram; let that minimal distance be **d**
- multiply the coordinate values with **200/d**

Another method would be to ramdomly select 2501 points from a square grid with width 200;

the density of the pointset can then be increased by turning the square grid into a triangular grid via multiplying the y-coordinates with 200*sqrt(3/2) and adding 100 to the x-coordinates of every other horizontal grid line.

Answer (score -1):

the following method uses list comprehension, but I am generating integers you can use different random generators for different datatypes
`arr = [[random.randint(-4, 4), random.randint(-4, 4)] for i in range(40)]`

Comment: Please re-read the question. The requirement is to exclude points that fall within a specified radius of another point.