# generate 50 points with minimum distance between them is 0.1

Tags: python

I want to generate 50 random coordinates in an unit square such that each point has minimum Euclidian  distance of 0.1 from other points. How can I generate such in python? Actually I need to know how to put condition in random number. But I could not find any way. One way I was using if command with that condition in it. But I need to generate 50 such points. Thanks for any help.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by random here? could you just select 50 random points from the 11x11 point grid (0,0),(0,0.1),(0,0.2) etc.?

Comment: @pygri I have the constraint of 0.1

Comment: please check these links [link1](http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/random/._random-solarized006.html) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668463/generating-multiple-random-x-y-coordinates-excluding-duplicates) may be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the generate-and-test solution described by Hanna Gabor:

```
import random
import math

npoints = 50
mindist = 0.1

def genpt():
    return (random.random(), random.random())

def distance(p1,p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0]-p2[0])**2 + (p1[1]-p2[1])**2)

sample = []

while len(sample) < npoints:
   newp = genpt()
   for p in sample:
      if distance(newp,p) < mindist: break
   else:
     sample.append(newp)

print(sample)
```

This works well for 50 points. The limit appears to be around 80 points.

As @pygri pointed out in a comment, one could also choose 50 random points from the 121 points spaced at intervals of 0.1 along the x and y axis from 0 to 1, since the distance between any two of these is guaranteed to not be less than 0.1. The following code will do this:

```
import random

npoints = 50

allpoints = [(a/10,b/10) for a in range(11) for b in range(11)]
sample = random.sample(allpoints, npoints)

print(sample)
```

Answer (score 4):

A cheap solution would be to keep generating random points in the square. If the generated point is not too close to the other points, then keep it, otherwise throw it away. Once you've reached 50 points, you can stop generating random points.

Comment: interesting point here would be, is this guaranteed to converge to a solution? 
I would imagine with 50 points it should be reasonably likely, but it may not work for e.g. 100 points and a bad starting point...

Answer (score 2):

you could pick 50 points from the regular grid `(0.1*i, 0.1*j)` for `i=0..10` and `j=0..10`

Comment: A neat solution.